How to use custom domain with Auth0 React SDK
I set up a custom domain, login.mydomain.com, in the Auth0 dashboard, and the status is marked as ready. I have integrated Auth0 authentication into my app using the Auth0 React SDK. Authentication works perfectly on localhost with the Auth0 default domain. However, when I switch to using the custom domain, authentication fails. When I enter login.mydomain.com in a browser, it redirects me to mydomain.com instead of the Auth0 login page.DNS records Here is my code:
 export const Auth0ProviderWithNavigate = ({ children }) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
  
    // const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
    const domain = 'login.mydomain.com'
    const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;
    // const organizationId = "org_DqLZEX65aFU4ftgv";
    // const redirectUri = "http://localhost:3000";

    const onRedirectCallback = () => {
        navigate('/');
    };

    return (
        <Auth0Provider
            domain={domain}
            clientId={clientId}
            authorizationParams={{
                redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
                // organization: organizationId 
            }}
            onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
        > 
            {children}
        </Auth0Provider>
    )
}

export default function LoginButton() {

  const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("handleing login")
      const domain = email.split('@')[1];
      const orgId = orgMap[domain]

      await loginWithRedirect({
        authorizationParams: {
          organization: orgId,
          // redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
          login_hint: email
        },
      });
    } catch(error){
      console.error("login error", error)
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        type="email"
        placeholder="Enter your email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Log In</button>
    </div>
  )
}

function App() { const { isLoading, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();  
   
  return (
   <div>
      {!isAuthenticated && <LoginButton />}
)}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    < BrowserRouter >
      <Auth0ProviderWithNavigate>
        <App />
      </Auth0ProviderWithNavigate>
    </ BrowserRouter >
);



I lookup in the DNS record and found records for login.mydomain.com
I replaced the domain value to login.mydomain.com

